# Why doesn't Microsoft provide a Docker image matching Windows host version 10.0.22621.1992

Tags: docker

#### Context

I'm using a **Windows 11 Pro** machine that has following ver :

```
C:\Users>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992]
```

I am using *Docker Desktop* in **windows container mode** and I would like to start a windows container with `--isolation=process` with the following command

```
docker run -it --rm --name container_name -v .:c:/localroot --isolation=process image_name
```

#### Problem

When using process isolation mode, it's crucial that the host operating system version matches the container image OS version. I've searched on Docker Hub, specifically the [Microsoft Windows page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows), but could only find Windows 10 images.

**Is there a specific reason Microsoft hasn't released a Docker image corresponding to the Windows host version 10.0.22621.1992?** Additionally, does anyone know of a suitable image or workaround for this?

#### Why I Opt for Process Isolation Mode in Docker

The source code resides on the host, and my objective is to compile it within the container. I utilize scons for the build process, which is highly I/O intensive. From extensive testing, I've observed that when the container operates in hyperv isolation mode, the build process is either significantly sluggish or occasionally fails altogether. By using process isolation mode, the container and the host share the same kernel. I believe this approach can enhance the build efficiency.

Thank you

Comment: How could a question about someone else's motives in what content they do and do not make an effort to publish be a _practical, answerable_ question about software development? No matter what those motives are it won't change how you go about the practice of writing code.

Comment: (whereas if the question about motive were factored out, you'd have an off-site resource request, which is a separate categorically-off-topic class of question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [10.0.22621.1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11) is W11 22H2 from 12 days ago (July 2023). It might be still a bit too fresh.

Second, containers are generally provided for [Microsoft Windows Server containers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5029079-windows-server-containers-for-july-2023-511170b1-669f-4cd7-9a5d-6a40972501f8), as discussed in  [`microsoft/Windows-Containers`/issue 117](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/117)

The alternative remains to use a [Windows Server 2022 image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-server), as requested in [`containerd/containerd` PR 8137](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/pull/8137)

> Windows 11 clients support running process-isolated containers of 10.0.20348 and above. Or to put it another way, Windows 11 clients can run Windows Server 2022 containers even when their build numbers don't match. Docker Engine already supports this scenario; this change updates containerd to make it also support this scenario.
>
> The [container/OS version compatibility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11#windows-client-host-os-compatibility) documents this level of compatibility between the client OS and server OS versions.

But in your case, the host operating system version won't match *exactly* the container image OS version